# How to get the system settings that I can find in the Appearance dialog?

Tags: settings, system, appearance

I need to get some system settings for example, font size and color for a standard dialog box? (I use C#)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following classes have properties that will give you the information you are after:

```
System.Drawing.SystemFonts
System.Drawing.SystemColors
System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation
```

In answer to the OPs comment:

```
Font messageBoxFont = System.Drawing.SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont;
```

Comment: systemfonts is just set of installed fonts, I need the font an user selected for message box for example, where is it, for example in System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation?